# C# send multiple values from TcpClient to remote server

Tags: c#, android, .net

I asked a similar question before, but I just can't seem to find a way to do it. I am making the android application using c#, I want to send data to the remote server for registration. I want to send first-last name, email, domain name and host name where hostname is the new internet name which I am going to give user machine. for example hostname.domainname.com. I have my own domain.

The server will send me key value as 123-01234. Now I am using TcpClient for it. There are commands of the server for First name FNAME, for last name LNAME, for email is EMAIL  and HOST for the hostname.

My question is that should I need to use the TCP listener or Socket for server-side or just need to use TcpClient and if I use TCP listener then How I will use commands on the server side. How I can send multiple values at the same time. Thank you in advance.

Here is my Client code:

```
public void Connect(String server)
{
    Int32 port = 123;
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
    string firstName= "mark";
    string lastName= "jj";
    string email= "mk@gmail.com";
    string host= "mk";
    string domain= "abc.com";
    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(firstName);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", FNAME);
    data = new Byte[256];
    String responseData = String.Empty;
    Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: `Server will send me key value as 123-01234. Now i am using TcpClient for it. ` TcpClient for a server? No way! So you are programming both server and client?

Comment: How does the server determine how many bytes of data the client is going to send, and visa versa?

Comment: That is my question. I don't know that should i programming for server or not. I just know that it is remote server and there are some commands of server that i described earlier. Right now, i am doing programming only for client. I want to know that should i programming for server if yes, then how i will use its commands ?

Comment: Use TcpListener on the server. When a client connects, the listener will produce a socket for that session. Use one of the TcpListener.Accept...() methods to get the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two (at least) part question. Let's focus on getting a connection started. Here is a basic example of how to listen on a socket and get set up to talk to the client:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 123);

try
{
    listener.Start();

    for (;;)
    {
        using (TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync())
        using (Stream stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            // Talk to client here.
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    listener.Stop();
}
```